# Run sudo command with password

Tags: linux, sudo

`sudo` command can be used in the following way

```
sudo -u <user_name> <command/script>
```

But I want to know how to include **password** as I want to avoid the user interactivity. Also, as an Admin, I don't want to disable password prompt for sudo commands. How can I achieve this. I tried `man sudo`, but not of much help.

Comment: I hope you understand that putting passwords in plain text files(scripts) is very risky in general. Try: `echo myAwesomePassword | sudo -S myCommand`. I am not putting this as an answer because this is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `-S` switch that reads password from `stdin`, example:

```
~$  echo "yourpassword" | sudo -S <command>
```

Anyway, as @Thrustmaster said, this is not the right way to use `sudo`.

Comment: What about `-u` option? Will I not be able to use it in this command?

Comment: You can use the `-u` option too

Comment: Then which is the right way to use `sudo` (with password option)?

Comment: @user1649068 you shouldn't, for security reasons, write passowrds on the `cli` or inside `scripts`

Comment: this maybe can be helpful when you want to execute sudo comands from java using Runtime.exec(command) i will try